# If I voted to close, should I downvote all answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, vote-to-close

If I voted to close a question, I usually mean "this question doesn't deserve answers". So it seems natural to vote all answers down.

However, voting should always refer to the content; if the content in a question affects a vote in the answer, it seems unnatural.

Also, one of the reasons for voting is arranging the answers according to their quality, and downvoting all of them doesn't help here at all.

On the other hand, not voting (or voting up) may somehow encourage people to answer questions which should be closed, leading to accumulation of bad content.

So I am undecided. Is there some reasoning I forgot to take into account?

Comment: It’s a sticky wicket. There is no objectively correct answer. Some people do, most don’t, but there isn’t a “right way” here. They’re your votes, you earned hem, spend them how you wish. I do this, but I typically reserve it for egregious cases (the whole broken windows thing), or from established users who should know better. By the way, you can be certain this question has been asked before on Meta, so don’t be upset or surprised if it’s closed as a dupe.

Comment: Related Meta.SE question: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/363946).

Comment: "*If I voted to close a question, I usually mean "this question doesn't deserve answers".*" That's not what closing means. Closing is about stopping people from answering questions which 1) are not really answerable without guessing, or 2) are not questions we want to support, for various reasons. It has nothing to do with what the question "deserves". Also, downvotes are not about punishment or sanctioning; they're about describing the *content of the post*.

Answer (score 12):

The issue of voting based on the quality of the answer rather than the question usually takes care of itself.

When a question really should be closed, any answers given are low quality for reasons that correspond to the close reason. Unclear questions attract guesses, recommendation questions attract opinions, etc., so if you're going to vote on them at all, down seems like the logical choice. They're not useful, and that's what the downvote is supposed to indicate. That's not downvoting based on the question, because you'd downvote an answer like that on any question.

On the other hand, if you see an answer that looks like it doesn't deserve a downvote, maybe you should reevaluate your decision to close the question. Sometimes it's possible for someone to understand a question well enough to answer it when it is unclear to others, or they may happen to know a simple solution to a problem that appears to be too broad.

Comment: What’s your take on the situation that typically causes me to downvote As to Qs, which is *the question is I researched, and didn’t need to be asked in the first place*? Now, typically, as you say, it has been my experience that simplistic questions attracted simplistic answers, and it’s fair enough to downvote bald assertions without reasoning or evidence. But they are still answers, and they do answer the question, usually objectively, though with little to no substantiation.

Comment: @DanBron In my opinion, if we give the questioner the benefit of the doubt, and assume they did some research, but didn't know what to look for, or didn't understand what they found (not saying we should always do this necessarily, but just for the sake of argument here) then it's especially important for any answer to include a proper explanation, because the OP and anyone else who may have the same question will need that for the answer to be useful at all, and any halfassed "try this" answer is especially deserving of a downvote.